# How to know the name of the resource from an Entity class, to build a Hateoas link to that resource?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

Suppose I have two resources `Person` and `Article`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long person_id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="person", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Article> articles = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
@Table(name="article")
public class Article {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    private String title;
    private String details;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="person_id")
    private Person person;

}
```

I now want to add HATEOAS support to the response of the controller for which I am using `org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceAssembler`

```
public class PersonResourceAssembler implements ResourceAssembler<Person, Resource<Person>>  {

    private EntityLinks entityLinks;

    public UserJobResourceAssembler(EntityLinks entityLinks) {
        this.entityLinks = entityLinks;
    }

    @Override
    public Resource<Person> toResource(Person entity) {
        Resource<UserJob> resource = new Resource<>(entity);
        resource.add(
               entityLinks.linkFor(Person.class).withSelfRel()),
               entityLinks.linkFor(...logic...).withRel("articles")) //here I am hardcoding the relation link name i.e "article"
             );
        return resource;
        }
}
```

So, in above code the "**article**" is hardcoded for the link name, but I don't want to do it this way. I want it do in the way `Spring-Data-REST` handles it i.e for every relationship it auto detects the name of the variable used inside the `Entity` class e.g `articles` will be picked from `Person` and `person` will be picked from `Article`.

I have no idea how `Spring-Data-REST` handles it, but are there any readymade/custom solutions for this requirement?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reflection API to introspect the entity and find associations. Something like:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

public class AssociationUtility {

    public static List<Field> getAssociatedFields(Object entity) {

        Stream<Field> fields = Arrays.stream(entity.getClass().getDeclaredFields());

        return fields.filter(field -> field.getAnnotation(OneToMany.class) 
                                  != null).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Field> fields = getAssociatedFields(new Customer());
        fields.stream().forEach(f -> System.out.println("Make a link for Class: "
                + ((ParameterizedType) f.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0] 
                     + " with rel: " + f.getName()));

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, inspired from your answer I wrote a better alternative using custom annotation. Will post the answer once basic testing is done.